# Return a grouped sum from a list

Tags: elixir

I just started with Elixir and this is what I have now. Is there an easier or better way to write this?

```
defmodule GroupBySum do
  def sum(col), do: sum(%{}, col)
  defp sum(r, [h|t]) do
    {k, v} = h
    r = r |> Dict.update(k, v, fn(val) -> val + v end)
    sum(r, t)
  end
  defp sum(r, []), do: r
end

list = [a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, a: 2, b: 1, c: 0]
IO.inspect GroupBySum.sum(list) #%{a: 3, b: 3, c: 3}
```

Comment: `Enum.reduce/3` is a more general wrapper for the recursion pattern you've implemented: http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.1/elixir/Enumerable.html#reduce/3 Also it might be more idiomatic to avoid needing the `h` variable by moving the `{k, v}` destructuring right into the parameters.

Answer (score 5):

It can be done several ways.  Instead of explicitly using recursion we can, as @alxndr suggested, make use of the recursion capabilities of the `Enum` module.  I am going to use `Enum.map_reduce` simply because I find it useful when troubleshooting to key the items and the accumulator in that form.

In general the solution is the same as yours.

```
  def sum(list) do
    list |> Enum.map_reduce([],
      fn({key, val}, acc) ->
        {{key, val}, Keyword.update(acc, key, val, &(&1 + val))}
      end
    ) |> elem(1)
  end
```

The anonmous function in map_reduce accepts and item and an accumulator.  Since the item is a keyword list, it has the form `{key,val}` so I match that  in the function definition.  The return from this function must be a tuple with the accumulator as the second value.  For testing purposes I returned the same `{key, val}` as the first item.  The Keyword.update function is the accumulator.  A form of this same routine that helps the intermediate values be visible is:

```
def sum(list) do
  list |> Enum.map_reduce([],
    fn({key, val}, acc) ->
      x = Keyword.update(acc, key, val, &(&1 + val))}
      IO.inspect(x)
      {{key, val}, x}
    end
  ) |> elem(1)
end
```

In the case of the input you provided, the `IO.inspect` helps me understand how the routine collected the desired result, as seen below.

```
[a: 1]
[a: 1, b: 2]
[a: 1, b: 2, c: 3]
[a: 3, b: 2, c: 3]
[a: 3, b: 3, c: 3]
[a: 3, b: 3, c: 3]
[a: 3, b: 3, c: 3]
```

I found this a fun exercise -- thanks for posting.

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview :) A fine and in-depth first answer, I hope you'll stick around!